# LNK1220: '/PGD' requires '/LTCG:[PGINSTRUMENT|PGOPTIMIZE]' specification

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

While building project in VS2008, I get the error

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1220: '/PGD' requires '/LTCG:[PGINSTRUMENT|PGOPTIMIZE]' specification
```

It was building fine earlier. I am not sure what I changed in properties and that causing this error now. My Linker -> Optimization settings are such Profile guided database is set to "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pgd" and all other fields are set to "Default". Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to do something with Profile Guided Optimization (PGO) or is this completely accidental ?

Comment: I got it resolved by setting "Link Time code generation as "Use Link Time Code Generation". Thnx.